# How can I detect patterns and/or keywords or phrases?

Tags: dataset

I am collecting data in a database via php from apache.

I am interested in detecting patterns in each column for now.

For example manual examination of the data shows the pattern *phpmyadmin* is various forms and capitalization and at different positions in the text.  Also to detect any other patterns.

How would I detect that programmatically using the computer instead of my brain?

I am going to need a detailed explanation as I am brand new to doing this kind of thing.

A pattern is any sequence of characters that repeat together. Like phpmyadmin is a sequence of 9 letters that repeat together. I detected "phpmyadmin" manually, I would like to detect it programmatically. Excluding single digit matches of common characters which is ascii 32-127

Comment: Using regex expressions + string library?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do and what you define as a "pattern". If you are interested in frequent terms, then tokenize and count the words. If you want to compare various forms of the same terms, I suggest you build two term matrices, one where you take the input as is and one where you take a version of the input that has been transformed to lower case.

BTW, a term frequency matrix is simply a matrix where the rows are your examples (I guess the columns in your database) and the columns are the discovered tokens (ie, the words)

For example, in the phrase 'the cat sat on the mat', the corresponding row vector of word counts would be:

```
the 2
cat 1
sat 1
on  1
mat 1
```

To get frequencies, you just divide the resulting vectors by the total count of words.

[EDIT] After reading the comments, I would recommend that you explore solutions for [anomaly detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection). [Here](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hpark/papers/textoutlier17.pdf) is a good paper that is tackling a similar problem as yours. The authors encode documents as bag of words using term frequencies (see above) and build a classifier to flag  a whole document as an outlier.

In your case, it is a little trickier because you want to flag specific terms as good or bad, and you don't have a labelled dataset. So either find a labelled dataset (no need for a fully labelled dataset, semi-supervised solutions exist but at least a few labels would be nice) or explore unsupervised solutions to outlier detection. As for pattern flagging, your best bet is to use recurrent neural networks, which are designed to process sequential data such as yours. That being said, I doubt you will achieve that with PHP, so maybe consider something else. Tensorflow / PyTorch / Neo4J are very good alternative for building such models and many other exist

Comment: A pattern is any sequence of characters that repeat together.  Like phpmyadmin is a sequence of 9 letters that repeat together.  I detected "phpmyadmin" manually, I would like to detect it programmatically.  Excluding single digit matches of common characters which is ascii 32-127.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? Does it work for you?

Comment: I am at kind of a loss on where to begin, since I haven't done this before.  I have thought of setting up arrays two[],three[],four[] and etc where each represent the number of letters inside. two(x)=mid(string,x,2)  three(x)=mid(string,x,3) and so on. Then searching each corresponding array and initiating a counter.  So if "aa" repeated then its counter would =2.  Then the count array could be sorted in descending order.  However, this all sounds very inefficient.

Comment: I can"t help you with php, but I'm pretty sure you should be able to find libraries to analyse text (a quick google search on "php tokenize text" gave me 96,000 results). Text processing is more my domain though and if I can give you an advice, you should first split the text rather than building all possible sequences of characters observed in your input. Maybe that if you explain why you want to do that, or what result you expect I will be able to help you

Comment: The data comes from a web server, where random people/bots request things many of which don't exist.  I would like to find the individual patterns so I can tag them good,bad, or indifferent.  A pattern like phpmyadmin is moved around just incase I renamed it.  Then if you get too many bad points the IP will be banned.

Comment: see my updated answer. Not sure if it helps but this is how I would tackle the problem...

Comment: I can do  pattern[mid(input,x,1)]+=1;pattern[mid(input,x,2)]+=1;pattern[mid(input,x,3)]+=1 and so on. increment x to the length(input).  However, its not very memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned any language preference but there are ways to do pattern recognition - I personally recommend using Python. The K-nearest neighbors, decorrelation and a dissimilarity matrix are a few ideas once you have defined what a pattern is.

Since you mentioned that you are new to all this - here are some really good sources to understand what needs to be done and how.

https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-basics-with-the-k-nearest-neighbors-algorithm-6a6e71d01761

http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/Dissimilarity_Matrix_Calculation

Comment: Welcome to DS SE! Would you please summarize your answer? We try to avoid link-only answers in case the links die. Thank you for contributing!